# How to copy a github local repo to another computer?

Tags: git, shell, github

I have a new PC and need to copy my local github for windows repos to the new computer.
All repositories are on github, but I do not want to download them all again to the new computer.

Is there any way to add this local files to the new computer using github for windows (or shell) and then just push/pull/sync the changes with the github.com?

Thank you all
Regards

Paulo

Comment: I have no idea how the GitHub app works, but in general, you should be able to literally just copy the top-level directory from one computer to the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are trying to avoid pushing unfinished local changes to the repo. No problem.

Git repos are self-contained. Just copy the repo directories from one machine to the other. Nothing fancy required.

Comment: It is not to avoid pushing unfinished changes to the repo. The idea is to have all repo (from the old machine) on the new machine and avoid downloading them all again from github. I have copied the repos from one machine to another as instructed and I can push/pull on the new machine using Git shell. The problem is that this repos are not shown on Github for windows itself. Any idea on how to make them appear also on github for windows repos list?

Comment: Sorry, I use a Mac, so I don't know about the Windows repo list. Just out of curiosity, though, why are you worried about downloading the repos again? Are you on a slow connection or something? It seems it would take longer to copy everything over than simply to clone the repos anew.

Answer (score 2):

You could clone your repos from another machine through local network with `git+ssh`

```
git clone git+ssh://user@192.168.1.5/~/repos
```

or just copy files and setup git on you new PC manually.

Comment: I have done that. The problem is that I cannot see the repos on Github for windows ( I can only use them on Git shell). If I try to manually add them, the system says that the repos already exist.

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation but with a Mac (not PC). With Mac, I backed up my old computer using Time machine and restored the new computer with that backup. So in essence all my data and profile from old transferred to new. To me it was pretty transparent. Basically, I was moving from a mac pro to mac air. All my git repos transferred too without any problems. I have a feeling Windows image would work similarly but to be honest I haven't done one myself. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

After copying your files from the old machine to the new, one needs to tell the GitHub app where your local files (repo) are.

In the GitHub app go to **[File\Add local repository...]** or **Ctrl+O**. Then you browse to the local folder with your repo. As explained by @user41871 , git repos are self-contained so GitHub will detect your repo in the local files and sync appropriately to your remote repo in GitHub.

Make sure you've installed Git before turning to GitHub. The GitHub app does not come with Git. Surprisingly the GitHub app 'works' even when Git is not installed.